# How to prevent a computer from accessing a git repository (after it has accessed it before)?

Tags: git, security, passwords, repository

I cloned a git repository onto a machine at an internet cafe and I am wondering if there is some way I can prevent future users from altering my repository from the same machine after I am done using it, I still have access to the machine as of time of writing and will for the next few days.

I'm a college student who isn't very familiar with git but I have to use it for homework purposes, I ended up using a computer in an internet cafe to work on homework. The git repository is password protected, I know the password, other people don't know the password, the password isn't saved on the computer anywhere, and I should be able to change the password if necessary but it might take some time. I already inputted the password once to be able to access my git repository, is there anything I can do to make sure future users on this machine will not be able to pull from or push to my repository? Sorry if this is a common mistake, I wasn't thinking about security at the time, thank you for your help.

I haven't tried many options because I am not familiar with git, it is a repository managed by my school, and I don't want to mess with/break anything. I can change the password but it is controlled by the administration, not me, and they are not going to be able to change it for me for at least a week. To be clear about what I am trying to do, I just do not want anyone to be able to change anything on my school's root repository, the clone of that repository on this machine and the associated files are unimportant. I can delete them but if other people see them or modify them it is unimportant, I just don't want them to be able to push files to this repository.

Answer (score 1):

Check first if you have a credential helper active on that computer:

```
git config --global credential.helper
```

That would have cached the credentials (username/password), allowing someone else to potentially (depending on the exact helper) to reuse said credentials.

Check also if your  internet cafe computer session is tied to a user-specific account (in which case, another user should *not* be able to access your files, or reuse your credentials).
Or if it is tied to a generic account (another user would then get the same session, and possible access your repository).

If it is the first case, make sure to clone your repository within your user account profile folder (`/home/me`, or `C:\Users\me`)